# Who is the statue in the opening stage of Mega Man X5 based on?

Tags: mega-man-x5

In the introduction stage of Mega Man X5, there is a statue that Sigma hides behind before attacking.

[image: statue]

I'd like to know what this is a statue of. Whoever she is, she has an entire park dedicated to her and Sigma managed to have the statue of her built around him. The (unofficial) wiki doesn't get much more specific than just calling it "a statue" and the English name for the stage is only called "Statue Park." Further, I don't know of any female characters in the original Mega Man games that resemble this woman.

Comment: What makes you think there's any lore at all behind it? The Mega Man games are not known for their deep story and motivation.

Comment: @Frank The music of Duff's stage, pre-boss banter talking about the events of the previous games, Iris in Zero's flashbacks, Dark Dizzy's Sigma insignia on his lifebar showing he's the only original Sigma designed boss, the return of Shadow Devil and accompanying music, the callback weapons used by X and Zero when they clash, the heavily implied return of Dr. Wily, and my personal favorite of Sigma's final body strongly resembling Gamma from Mega Man 3 all spring to mind. This game is littered with bits of lore and callbacks, moreso than any other MMX to my knowledge.

Comment: Well, here's a 100% JPN run, for anyone that can read it and give more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkP4jAoIrdo